# Define a function for symbols with UpValues

Tags: function-construction, upvalues

Suppose that we define UpValues for different symbols

```
isSpecialFunction[N1]^=True
isSpecialFunction[N2]^=True
isSpecialFunction[N3]^=True
```

I would like to make the following definition

```
func_?isSpecialFunction[]:= func[t,x]
```

such that every time I write e.g. `func[]` Mathematica substitutes it with `func[t,x]` only if `isSpecialFunction[func]==True`.

However, `func_?isSpecialFunction[]:= func[t,x]` is not a good definition because I get the error `SetDelayed: "func_?isSpecialFunction[] does not contain a symbol to attach a rule to.` What is the proper procedure to give the aforementioned definition for symbols with UpValues defined in this way?

Please, keep in mind that I want to use the fact that these symbols have UpValues. That's because I am using a package (`xCoba`), which defines ScalarFunctions with these UpValues and I want to substitute all the ScalarFunctions that appear as `func[]` with `func[t,x]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

isSpecialFunction[N1] ^= True;
isSpecialFunction[N2] ^= True;
isSpecialFunction[N3] ^= True;
```

Define a replacement [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)

```
rule = func_?isSpecialFunction[] :> func[t, x];
```

Add application of the `rule` to [`$Pre`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre.html)

```
$Pre := # /. rule &;
```

Testing,

```
{N1[], N2[], N3[], N4[]}

(* {N1[t, x], N2[t, x], N3[t, x], N4[]} *)
```

To clear `$Pre`

```
$Pre =.
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about $Pre! It's very useful!